# How can I use the Google Maps API to allow me to add several defined areas?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to make a little app to define an area on google maps and then it would put out the cost of lawn mowing service.

Is it possible to allow the user to define several areas? For example front and back Garden?

So far I havn't been able to figure out how to 'end' the first area definition and start a new one.

This is what I have right now.

```js
var poly;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite',
    center: {
      lat: 52.486741,
      lng: -2.8055232
    }
  });
  var area = 0;
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    strokeColor: '#f32222',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    editable: true,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'insert_at', calcArea);
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'set_at', calcArea);


  // Add a listener for the click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addLatLngToPoly(event.latLng, poly);
  });

  document.getElementById("clearPoly").onclick = function() {
    area = 0;
    document.getElementById("areaValue").value = area;
    poly.setPath([]);
    path = poly.getPath();
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'insert_at', calcArea);
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'set_at', calcArea);
  }
}

function addLatLngToPoly(latLng, poly) {
  var path = poly.getPath();
  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear
  path.push(latLng);
  calcArea();
}

function calcArea() {
  var path = poly.getPath();
  area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(path);
  area = (Math.trunc(area));
  document.getElementById("areaValue").value = area;
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
  <p>Area:</p>
  <p><textarea id="areaValue"></textarea>m</p>
  <button id="clearPoly">Clear</button>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

At the end I'd like to be able to use a simple calculation such as (area * 0.5) to calculate and show a price.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer)?  It allows multiple polygons to be added to a map.

Comment: As far as I'm aware though, that doesn't then let you compute the area within the paths drawn?

Comment: That would be done with geometry library

Comment: Use the drawingManager. Use the drawn Polygon path in your `calcArea` function, just like you did for the standard Polygon.